# Multiplatform Configuration Tool in Java

Tags: java, html

I am working on a configuration tool that needs to work in Windows, Solaris, and Linux.  The GUI for the tool will communicate with a service thread that periodically reads information from certain hardware.

I want to use a web interface for the tool, essentially serving configuration options through dynamic HTML and CSS.  This will ensure that the GUI looks consistent across platforms and I can avoid the use of applets (tool should be accessible through browser).

So my question is, is there any simple way to get Java to serve web pages (similar to WSGI in Python) and listen for HTTP POST events? I would like to only use the Java standard libraries, and the tool will more-or-less only be accessed by one person at a time.

Answer (score 0):

There's the `com.sun.net.httpserver` package in the JDK, if you are determined not to use a library, but I recommend using something like Spring MVC for the HTML/HTTP handling combined with Maven for your build scripts. There's a bit of a learning curve, but you can probably just adapt one of the tutorial applications quite quickly.